# I want to write this SQL in Laravel Eloquent -select all author names belongs to a book

Tags: php, laravel

I want to write this SQL in Laravel Eloquent

```
SELECT book.book_id,book.book_name,author.author_name,book.price,book.publication   
FROM author,book,book_author
WHERE bookauthor.b_id=book.book_id and bookauthor.a_id=author.author_id
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a better approach using the [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships). The Book model should have defined the following relationship:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the authors for the book.
     */
    public function authors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Author');
    }
}
```

and the authors should belong to the book:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the book of the author.
     */
    public function book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Book');
    }
}
```

If you want to get only the authors names you can use the [reduce](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-reduce) method on the authors collection:

```
$authors = App\Book::find(1)->authors;

$authorsNames = $authors->reduce(function ($carry, $author) {
    $carry[] = $author->name;
    return $carry;
}, array());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Laravel Joins:

```
  bookauthor::Join('book', 'book.book_id', '=', 'bookauthor.b')
->Join('author','bookauthor.a_id','=','author.author_id')
->select('book.book_id','book.book_name','author.author_name','book.price','book.publication')
->get();
```

Try this. Good luck :)